# JSON arrays using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm having an array "pollAnswers" which displays:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Sachin
    [1] => Dhoni
)
```

in PHP and I want it to display as:

```
"pollAnswers":[
    {"pollAnswersID":0, "pollAnswer":"Sachin"}, 
    {"pollAnswersID":1, "pollAnswer":"Dhoni"}
]
```

in JSON output.

I've tried using [array_fill_keys](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill-keys.php) and [array_flip](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php) but that's not solution for this. It seems I need to split the array_keys and array_values and then do some concatenation to get this, but I'm stuck here!

Comment: you have to re-design your array.

Answer (score 3):

Online check [link](https://3v4l.org/vPPXt)

**Try this**

```
$arr = array("Sachin", "Dhoni");

$sub_arr = array();
$final = array();

foreach($arr as $key => $val){
    $sub_arr['pollAnswersId'] = $key;
    $sub_arr['pollAnswer'] = $val;

    $sub_final[] = $sub_arr;
}

$final['pollAnswers'] = $sub_final;
echo json_encode($final);
```

**result**

```
{"pollAnswers":[
    {"pollAnswersId":0,"pollAnswer":"Sachin"},
    {"pollAnswersId":1,"pollAnswer":"Dhoni"}
]}
```

Comment: You konow  Rising Pune Supergiants team  Dhoni,               Rishi Bro plz accept Answer .

Comment: Frayne relax just kidding in indian style @@

Answer (score 2):

You can try with `array_map`.

```
$Array = array('Sachin', 'Dhoni');

$new = array_map(function($v, $k) {
    return ['pollAnswersId' => $k, 'pollAnswer' => $v]; // return the sub-array
}, $Array, array_keys($Array)); // Pass the values & keys

var_dump(json_encode(array("pollAnswers" => $new)));
```

**Output**

```
"{"pollAnswers":[
    {"pollAnswersId":0,"pollAnswer":"Sachin"},            
    {"pollAnswersId":1,"pollAnswer":"Dhoni"}
]}"
```

For older versions of **PHP**.

```
return array('pollAnswersId' => $k, 'pollAnswer' => $v);
```

[Fiddle](https://eval.in/563611)

Comment: @PedroLobito It would work if you have replaced the shorthand array syntax. Though, OP didn't mention about the version.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$answerArray = [];

foreach($yourArray as $key => $r) 
    $answerArray[] = ['pollAnswersId' => $key, 'pollAnswer' => $r];

echo json_encode($answerArray);
```

Here you go.

Comment: Not properly created as OP want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$givenArray = array("Sachin","Dhoni");

$answerArray = []; 

foreach($givenArray as $key => $r) 
    $answerArray[] = ['pollAnswersId' => $key, 'pollAnswer' => $r];

echo $out = json_encode(array('pollAnswers' => $answerArray));
```